# How can I emulate the browser zoom

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

I'm searching a way to emulate the browser zoom. I found different approaches but nothing works well for me. For example, the "zoom" property doesn't seem to work on firefox. The -moz-transform doesn't act like ctrl++

Maybe there is a jQuery plugin or a CSS3 property to do that ? Or maybe I misused the zoom property on Firefox ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[CSS3 transformation function: scale](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions)**. I think it should do the trick for you. I'll post an example ASAP.

**[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/45pp3/)**, it uses the transform property with scale, and `transform-origin: top left` (otherwise it will scale it from the middle, change as you see fit).

All the necessary documentation is in the first link I gave you ([this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions)).